The default parameters of the Swift addtarget method do not take effect
This is my code:
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let btn = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100));
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testAction(_:animated:)), for: .touchDown)
        view.addSubview(btn)
    }
    @objc func testAction(_ sender: UIButton,animated: Bool = true){
        if sender.backgroundColor == UIColor.red {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }else{
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        print("animated == \(animated)")
    }
}


As shown in the picture, a button is added to the test project. The method has default parameters, but the animated parameter is printed as false. Can anyone tell me why? I would be very grateful.
Is this a system bug? I have tested this in many scenarios.

Your button btn is out of scope as soon as ViewDidLoad closure is done.

Check if the button's state changes appropriately when touched down. For example, you can change the button's background color or title to provide visual feedback when it's touched.

@soundflix. Why does exceeding the range cause the value of the default parameter to be incorrect?

'button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testAction(_:animated:)), for: .touchDown)'
'@objc func testAction(_ sender: UIButton, animated: Bool = true) try like this'

@NewbieiOS I uploaded the latest code but it's still like this, I feel it's a system bug

let animated = true // or false, depending on your needs
if sender.backgroundColor == UIColor.red {
sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
} else {
sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
print("animated == (animated)")  please check the console now. while clicking the button, whether it is changing the value true or false

You are using the TargetAction mechanism from the Objective-C. As per documentation, only sender and event are valid arguments and anything else would have undefined behaviour.

The UIButton calls testAction by performing the selector you passed to action: on the object you passed to target:, using a method like performSelector:withObject:. This is inherently an Objective-C thing, and Swift parameters' default values just don't work in Objective-C.
In Objective-C, func testAction(animated: Bool = true) is imported as if it doesn't have an optional parameter. The header looks like this:
- (void)testActionWithAnimated:(BOOL)animated;

UIButton expects its action to be a method that takes a parameter representing the "sender" of the event, and it would be pass itself (an UIButton instance) as the argument.
So what happens here is that the animated parameter gets passed a pointer to an instance of UIButton, which is forcefully interpreted as a BOOL (because Objective-C has a rather weak type system). The result of that happens to be false.
If you declare testAction with two parameters,
@objc func testAction(_ sender: UIButton, animated: Bool = true)

UIButton would pass a UIEvent instance to the second parameter, and this again gets interpreted as a boolean, and the result happens to be false.

Thank you for your answer. When I don't pass the sender, animated is still false. How can I make it run correctly? I didn't find the way to bind the action to the button in swift.

@godpp Just do @objc func testAction()? The animated parameter is useless - nothing will be passed to it in any case.

Or just have two methods @objc func testAction() and func testAction(animated: Bool), and have one call the other.
